# Son 2-3 years old doesn't want to eat porridge/cereal

Tags: food, eating

Dear parents and parenting specialists. What to do if my son doesn't want to eat porridge/cereal? We try everything, we want him to eat buckwheat, millet, oatmeal, muesli and semolina, but he refuses. In need of advice.

Comment: In what way does he refuse it? Spitting it out? Ignoring it?

Comment: @L.B. He mostly rejects it and doesn't open his mouth, if we force it in he spits it out.

Comment: @My guess then would be he either doesn't like the smell or has had one bad experience with the taste of what he's being given and doesn't want to try it again.

Comment: @L.B. Maybe pluck his nose with something before he starts eating? Will it help? )) Kidding... Yeh, we did give him semolina cereal and he eat a bit of it.

Comment: Lol... I'm not sure I'd go that far with it :) Perhaps a bit of cinnamon (well mixed), vanilla or maple syrup would help. In my personal experience buckwheat isn't much fun to eat, so I could see him turning his nose up at that :) You could buy regular prepackaged dry cereal such as Cheerios , put milk in them to soften it thoroughly and see if he'll eat that.

Comment: Hope to try it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That in itself is nothing to worry about.  You may continue to offer cereal occasionally, without pushing or feeling any alarm if it is rejected.

A nutritionally balanced repertoire, with  enough variety to keep things interesting, is what you should be aiming for.

The American Academy of Pediatrics has built a website aimed at parents, www.healthychildren.org.  In the section called Healthy Living, there is a section on toddler and preschooler nutrition, which says, in part:

> Toddlers and preschoolers grow in spurts and their appetites come and go in spurts, so they may eat a whole lot one day and then hardly anything the next. It's normal, and as long as you offer them a healthy selection, they will get what they need.

Answer (score 2):

Our 3 year old doesn't like things that are mushy and would rather eat the cereal/granola dry with something to wash it down. It takes him a long time to eat it so our preference is scrambled eggs, toast and fruit or french toast and fruit.